# Poor sympy linsolve/ solve performance

Tags: python, performance, math, simulation, sympy

I'm using sympy to solve a simple linear system of equations.

It's a coupled ODE, there are time-derivatives of variables and I need to solve the system of equations for the highest derivatives.
Since sympy doesn't allow me to solve for statements like `phi_1.diff(t)`, I've replaced all derivatives with placeholder symbols.

For example:

> phi.diff(t).diff(t) + phi(t) =0

becomes

> ddphi + phi(t) = 0

This works fine. The solutions are correct and I can simulate the system - it's a pendulum: https://youtu.be/Gc_V2FussNk

The problem is that solving the system of equations (with `linsolve`) takes very long.

For just 2 equations, it takes 2 seconds.
For 3 equations, it's still calculating (after over 10 minutes).

**EDIT:** @asmeurer advised me to try out solve instead.
For n=3, linsolve took about 34 minutes - I only made one measurement.
`solve` takes 31 seconds (averages over 3 runs).

Still, I believe that a linear 3x3 system should be solved in fractions of a second.

And for n=4 `solve` becomes unbearably slow, too (still calculating)

I've formatted the code and created an iPython notebook: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/bec52b222d1d8d28e0d1baf77d545ec5
If you scroll down a little, you can see the formatted output of the system of equations and directly below that the call to `linsolve`

The equations are rather long but strictly linear in the second derivatives.
I'm sure that this system can be solved.
All I need to do is solve a 3x3 system of linear equations where the coefficients might be symbols.

Is there a more performant way to do this ?

Comment: You should also provide the jacobian to **odeint** if you want the solution to be more performant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But for the 2-pendulum odeint wasnt the bottleneck. So far I havent even reached that line of code with 3 pendulums.

Comment: Your differential equations don't look linear to me.  Some of the first order derivative terms of phi are squared in your set of equations.

Comment: @mtadd sure that's right. But I'm not solving for the first order derivatives, only for the second order. The solver should be able to handle them like constants.

Comment: Looks like `solve` is faster than `linsolve`.

Comment: @asmeurer Oh, you're right. And by quite a bit. I actually waited for linsolve to complete: took 35min. Solve on the other hand only needs 31 seconds. This is only a solution for n=3 though. I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: The problem is that `linsolve` calls `simplify`, which is slow, and there's no way to disable it. `solve` does have a flag, though, `simplify=False`. Does that help any?

Comment: @asmeurer thanks for that amazing tip. Just tried that flag and it makes a gigantic difference. 3 pendulum in 1.7s , 4 pendulum in 4.6s, 5 pendulum in 30s. This is a huge progress. Still I think that a 5x5 system of equations shouldn't take 30s to solve. Do you think there's still room for improvement ? Honestly, I've got basically no experience with sympy and don't  know its limitations

Comment: You could play with the other flags to [solve](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve). I'm not an expert in it.

Comment: @asmeurer I did that. There is a flag which disables the conversion of floats to rationals - this brings another huge boost. Now I can simulate pendulums up to order 7 and 8. The integration of the ODE is becoming the bottleneck. Thank you very much. If you convert this into an answer: "Tuning the flags will improve performance" I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`solve` (not `linsolve`) has some flags that you can set which can make it faster:

- `simplify=False`: disables simplification of the result.
- `rational=False`: disables the automatic conversion of floats to rationals.

There is a warning in the `solve` docstring that `rational=False` can lead to some equations not being solvable due to issues in the polys, so be aware that that's a potential issue.

Comment: Good to point out the danger of rational. I was wary at first, too

Comment: I believe at worst if `rational=False` fails, you will get an exception from `solve`.

Comment: In my case (simple linear equation with many variables) the 'simplify=False' improved speed 100 times, with the same result. Great!

Answer (score 2):

I have found that solve can be very slow in jupyter notebook if you have run sp.init_printing() before your equations. I have a module "equations" where I write my equations and solve them.

This is faster:

```
import sympy as sp
import equations
sp.init_printing()
```

Than this:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
import equations
```

Comment: This sounds like something that should be reported as a bug